# how can I remotely connect to my mongodb started by mongod

Tags: linux, mongodb

I am working on MongoDB lately, and get stuck in connecting to mongoDb remotely.

I have a folder called db, and this is my dbpath folder as well.

I started the mongodb by type:

```
mongod --dbpath=./db
```

Then I connect to it in another terminal by typing

```
mongo
```

Then I navigated to etc/mongod.conf file, commented out the

`bindIp : 127.0.0.1`

However, I am still not capable of connecting to my mongoDb with mongobooster or another other GUI tools.

Wondering where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bindIp : 127.0.0.1` makes mongodb listening on local interface only.

Change it to `bindIp : 0.0.0.0` to make it listening on all interfaces, but consider [security issues](https://www.darknet.org.uk/2017/01/mongodb-ransack-33000-databases-hacked/).

Ideally leave it bound to localhost, and use ssh tunnel to connect to it, or bind it to private network, either phisical, or virtual, depending on your setup.

Comment: Did you restart the the server after changing config? Can you connect to the remote db with command line `mongo`? Check if any firewall blocks the port using telnet. Add logs of mongodb to the question.

Comment: I did so, but I figured the problem is the security group setting on my server